# How to ignore uploading a image file by using Nodejs and multer

Tags: node.js, multer, image-file

i am a beginner of nodejs and I'm using multer to upload image file.  I want the user to be able to submit a form where posting an image is optional
However , if i submit and skip the selection of image file , an error will occur: " Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'destination')".
Can anyone tell me how to handle when user submit a form without select image file.

this is code:

```
const multer = require('multer');
const path = require('path');


const storage = multer.diskStorage({
destination: (req,file,cb) => {
    cb(null,'public/images/words');
},
filename:(req,file,cb)=>{
    console.log(file);
    cb(null, Date.now() + path.extname(file.originalname));
}
});

const upload = multer({storage:storage});

module.exports = upload;
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PfFJV.png)

Comment: Can you show the code that the error is talking about? The submitWord function?

Comment: i'm very appreciate because you have commented but i have solved this issue. The error is in the submitWord. Anyway thank you very much.

Comment: Ok, remember to always read your stack traces.